# Report viewer textbox visibility expression

Tags: c#, vb.net, report-viewer2010

I am trying to get a text box and tablix to toggle their visibility based on an expression.

I have tried the following:

```
=IIF(First(Fields!Supported.Value, "FooDataSet") = "true", True, False)
```

However, this will not work for me. I'm using the 2010 version and using it in local mode.

I also tried writing custom code to see if that would work:

```
Public Function ToggleVisibility(ByVal visible As string) As Boolean
  Dim isVisible As Boolean = False
  If visible = "true" Then
    isVisible = True
  End If
  Return isVisible
End Function
```

Then I use it in the "Show or hide based on an expression" under the Visibility item in the text box and tablix properties.

```
=Code.ToggleVisiblity(First(Fields!Supported.Value, "FooDataSet"))
```

This also does not work for me.

Comment: Hi, Please have a look at the answer provided below. Thats how the visibility of a textbox is set.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I see the visibility for a textbox and it worked.

I did the following

1. Right Clicked the textbox control
2. Clicked Textbox Properties... => Visibility
3. Selected show or hide based on an expression and clicked the fx button
4. In the expression editor, I added the following code.

> =IIF(First(Fields!Author.Value, "DataSet1")="Romulus",true,false)

Note in this editor, you are setting the expression for **Hidden** and not **Visibility**, so be careful on passing the values. In my case since Romulus was not a Author, the condition was evaluated to **false** and the textbox was **visible**

Answer (score 0):

It should work even without `IIF`.

```
=First(Fields!Supported.Value, "FooDataSet") = "true"
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasted an hour for this,

THE THING IS IT IS JUST hiding the report item IF YOUR EXP VALUE IS TRUE, and showing it if the exp value is false ...... WHICH IS frustrating